# How to align item in list view side by side in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My Requirements is to arrange items like this in listview:

```
item 1  item2
item 3  item4
item 5  item6
```

I'm currently using ListView and its children as Wrap widget(to arrange item in next line)
My Output is like this

```
item 1 item 4
item 2 item 5
item 3 item 6
```

How to achieve my requirement in the flutter

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is by using `GridView`. It is really meant for that kind of layout that you needed.
Here is an [example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists) of how to use a `GridView`:

```
GridView.count(
  // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
  // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
  children: List.generate(100, (index) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Item $index',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
      ),
    );
  }),
);
```

Here is a picture showing the layout difference between `GridView` and `ListView`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Uni answerd to use Grid-view, and that's 100% correct, but if you need a setup like this:

--Widget1-- --Widget2--
--------Widget3--------
--Widget4-- --Widget5--

You could use Listview, but then have the Widget1 and Widget2 in a Row(), And that way there will only be 1 widget(Row) on each line, but that widget(Row) will have 2 child-widgets, or more, on the inside.
This gives a lot more flexibility than Gridview, but to be honest if you need the function of gridview, then use that, I even use it, but Listview with rows can be helpfull for a more dynamic design :)